# Can you loop a CMD ping in AutoIt

Tags: loops, ping, autoit

so i tried to make a dos tool that sends lots of 32 byte pings towards a target ip but it wont run this is probably a minor error i missed out i cant find it. i tried making a loop that would just type in the "ping " instead of having to open a new one each time but the same thing happened can i also mention im really new to AutoIt so dont go screaming at me.

heres what i wrote:

```
While run("Command Prompt")
WinWaitActive("Command Prompt")
Send("ping <ip address>")
send("{Enter}")
WinWaitClose()
send("!n")
WEnd
```

Comment: why don't you use AutoIt's built-in [ping](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/Ping.htm)?

Comment: oh................................. thanks